# Netty FrameDecoder not invoked in ChannelPipeline without carriage return?

Tags: java, netty, nio

I'm working with Netty and it seems that a FrameDecoder in a ChannelPipeline isn't invoked unless/until a carriage return is received. For example, I have the following decoder that I've written to attempt to detect when a complete JSON string has been received:

```
public class JsonDecoder extends FrameDecoder {
    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, ChannelBuffer buf) {
        char inChar = 0;
        ChannelBuffer origBuffer = buf.copy();
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        int ctr = 0;
        while(buf.readable()) {
            inChar = (char) buf.readByte();
            json.append(inChar);
            if (inChar == '{') {
                ctr++;
            } else if (inChar == '}') {
                ctr--;
            }
        }
        if (json.length() > 0 && ctr == 0) {
            return origBuffer;
        } 
        buf.resetReaderIndex();
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Please pardon the somewhat sloppy code - this is my first attempt using Netty and a bit of a learning experience.)

What I see happen is that this works fine when I test it by connecting to the server using telnet, paste in some valid JSON and press return. However, if I do not press return after the final closing '}' in the JSON string, the decoder never gets called with an updated buffer.

Is there a way to configure the channel pipeline to work differently? I've Googled for this and looked through the Netty documentation. I feel like I'm missing something basic and I just am not looking in the right place or searching for the right thing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned that this is just raw JSON coming over a TCP socket connection - no HTTP protocol involved.

Answer (score 1):

Is your telnet client reverting to 'old line by line' mode whereby only completed lines are sent to the server ([telnet man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?telnet))? Try writing a simple Java client to send the message instead.

Comment: Doesnt matter in this case. The FrameDecoder base class doesn't "relay" the message until it has seen the entire frame (i.e. read the new line)

Comment: I don't follow. FrameDecoder doesn't know anything about how frames are delimited. In the example the JsonDecoder determines that by returning non-null when it has read the frame, which it determines by matching opening and closing braces. ReplayingDecoder helps with this, but isn't a requirement. My point about telnet 'old line by line' mode is that this would cause the client to buffer data until enter was pressed. This would seem to match the fact that it works if the client disconnects which flushes the client buffers.

Comment: Oops, you're correct. I mistakenly assumed that DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder was used. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I guess reading a JSON stream is more akin to reading an HTTP stream, since you will have to keep track of the opening and closing braces (and brackets as well, should the JSON string be an array). If you look at the source for the HTTP decoder, you'll see that it is using a ReplayingDecoder. Using a replaying decoder is not necessary, but it helps a lot if the entire message is split in more than one buffer.

FrameDecoders are meant for reading messages that are "framed" by special characters (hence the name of the decoder) or prepended with a length field.

I would also highly recommend using the DecoderEmbedder helper class so that you can unit test your JSON decoder without doing actual I/O.

Comment: Thanks! I will try the ReplayingDecoder - I'm optimistic this will fix the problem based on your answer and reading the documentation more. Will accept your answer once I have a chance to try it.

Comment: What I'm noticing after extending ReplayingDecoder is that decode is only getting called when the client disconnects. Clients will actually have a persistent connection with the server and will not disconnect under normal conditions, so I need to have decode() called on an on-going basis. Is there a way to do this with ReplayingDecoder? Or should I be using something like the IdleThreadHandler in conjunction with the ReplayingDecoder to somehow trigger the buffer to be read if there is no activity for some reasonably short period of time?

Comment: decode() is called whenever there's data in the receive buffer. Something else is going on; maybe the client buffers data; hard to say without more details.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using telnet to test. I can try the DcoderEmbedder as you suggested to rule out the client, but I doubt that the telnet client is buffering. Is there something else I should be doing when I configure the pipeline or bootstrap the server?

Comment: Yes, try the DecoderEmbedder. Then you can also easily test that your decoder can handle split messages. Your Decoder should be pretty standalone, but of course it depends if there are other handlers preceding it in the pipeline.

Comment: @Chris Hart. Sorry, I was wrong in assuming that you were using DelimiterBasedFrameEncoder (I cannot read, obviously). However, the advice to use DecoderEmbedder is still valid, I think.